# What is the best solution to serve from multiple API's on a PHP backend?

Tags: php, laravel, logic, backend, lumen

I'm building an API with [Laravel's Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) and I've realized that the main task of my API will be to serve data from other API's.

I really don't know which one is the best approach to get the best performance on this.

I came up with two solutions:

- **Everytime a user makes a request, I call the different API's in order to serve the request.**

  I think the main problem on this will be the time that will take to answer the request since it depends on all the API's being called.
- **Every X seconds call each API (with a cron) and keep my database updated and then serve each request from database and not directly other API's.**

  I see it as a super bad approach, since I'll be wasting a lot of resources each seconds even If no one needs the data at the moment.

The problem I see is the other API's data is constantly changing, so I must serve updated data.

So I'm really hoping there's any other better solution for this kind of problem. I wonder how big companies approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: This is somewhat opinion-based and API-specific. If the API does not have a request limit, then you need to take speed into account. Remember the more requests going on to other servers, the slower the response to your own user will be. If the API does have a request limit (5 requests per minute, 500 requests per hour, etc), then you'll want to cache it into a database on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is a micro service architecture.
In my compagny (big ecommerce website), we are developping 5 micro services, and 2 gateways.

When clients asks for data, it's directed to our gateways (either back or front related).
Then, our business logic is applied, and we call differents micro services to serve fresh data (or cached data whenever we can).

Of course, you must have fast and effective micro services.
To do so, you have to use ORM cache (for example, our micro services uses Symfony, so we have made Doctrine to works with Redis).
Also, you DB queries must be optimized.

You second approach can works, but will be painfull to maintain and will be very expansive for your database, since ALL your data will be crawled.
This is not "micro service compliant", since the result is having a big database in front, that is populated by many smaller databases

In conclusion, big companies uses micro services as I described first, with RESTFul API or GRAPHQL technologies

Comment: Wow I didn't realize about this, never thought in microservices when trying to find a better solution. I'll read deeply about microservices because it seems to be the perfect solution for what I want to build.

Thank you so much Juyn!!